# Is there a convertor that can convert a whole html code to only its elements(tree) so i can use it for scss

Tags: html, json, sass, converters

Is there any converter that can convert a whole HTML page to only its elements so I can apply sass on it?
I have also written the CSS code for the HTML in case someone has an idea on how I can do this faster.

**Example**
**THIS**

```
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Yeezy Shoets</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">From from 1400 until 1700, both courtesans and noble ladies wore chopines in her totower over others. During the Renaissance, chopines were a item for women, and they grew
                                    in height;</p>
                                <h3 class="text-start">2020</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="assets/1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**TO**

```
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h5></h5>
                                <p></p>
                                <h3></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <img >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why wouldnt you apply sass to the classes instead of the elements?  Suppose you have another page with similar elements that you want to appear different? Thats what the classes are for

Comment: In most cases, I believe that it would be a terrible idea to select only html element, except if you're working on a very specific framework to target, title, paragraph, etc... If you insist to do that, you could make a loop to strip the `classList` and all `attributes` and recursively run the function if the element has `children`.